# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3

Tags: java, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception, stringbuffer

I am making a program which determines whether or not two words are anagrams of one another. However, I have the following error and I'm not entirely sure why:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4

I have only included this method and not the entire program because this is the method where the error supposedly occurs.

```
public StringBuffer differentCharacters() 
{
    StringBuffer difference = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=0; i<StringBuffer1.length(); i++) 
    {
        if(StringBuffer1.charAt(i) != StringBuffer2.charAt(i))
        {
            difference.append(StringBuffer1.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return difference;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `StringBuffer2`'s size is less than `StringBuffer1`'s. Which causes the exception. Show us more code.

Comment: Why would that cause an exception?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the you are calling the `StringBuffer2` with an illegal index. Here's why:

You got 3 `StringBuffer`s in general: **difference**, **StringBuffer1** & **StringBuffer2**.

**Explanation:**

```
StringBuffer difference= new StringBuffer();
```

This is where you create the 'result' `StringBuffer`. Now let's imagine for a second that :

1. **StringBuffer1**'s `length` is 5
2. **StringBuffer2**'s `length` is 3

*Execution:*

```
for (int i = 0; i < StringBuffer1.length(); i++)
```

In this loop, you are iterating based on the **StringBuffer1**'s length (5). So here's what happens:

*i = 0*

```
if(StringBuffer1.charAt(0) != StringBuffer2.charAt(0))
```

*i = 1*

```
if(StringBuffer1.charAt(1) != StringBuffer2.charAt(1))
```

*i = 2*

```
if(StringBuffer1.charAt(2) != StringBuffer2.charAt(2))
```

*i = 3*

```
if(StringBuffer1.charAt(3) != StringBuffer2.charAt(3))
```

**Hold it right there !** 
Remember that **StringBuffer2**'s length equals 3 ? which means that the following :

```
StringBuffer2.charAt(3) // 0 based index : 0-1-2-3 crash !!
```

is illegal. Hence a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown, & the execution fails.